# returning vector by value with multiple function nesting in C++

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

For some reason, I want to return an object of my::Vector (which is basically a wrapper class that internally use STL vector for actual storage plus do provide some extra functions). I return vector by value as the function creates a vector locally every time.

```
my::Vector<int> calcOnCPU()
{
  my::Vector<int> v....
  return v;
}
```

Now I can have multiple nesting of function calls (considering a library design), so in short something like following:

```
my::Vector<int> calc()
{
    if(...)
      return calcOnCPU();
}
```

AFAIK, returning by value would invoke copy constructor of my::Vector class which is something:

```
Vector<int>::Vector(const Vector& c)
{
   ....
   m_vec = c.m_vec; // where m_vec is std::vector<int>
}
```

Few questions:
1) In copy constructor, is it invoking copy constructor of std::vector? or assignment operator and Just to confirm, std::vector creates deep copy (meaning copies all elements considering basic integer type).
2) With nesting of calcOnCPU() in calc() each returning Vector of int: 2 or 1 copies of Vector will be created? How could I avoid multiple copies in case of such simple method nesting? Inline functions or there exist another way?

**UPDATE 1:** It became apparent to me that I need to keep my own copy constructor as there are some custom requirements. However, I did a simple test in main function:

```
int main() {
   ...
   my::Vector v = calc();
   std::cout<<v;
}
```

I put some prints using "std::cerr" in my copy constructor to see when it gets called. Interestingly, it is not called even once for above program (atleast nothing gets printed). Is it copy ellision optimization? I am using GNU C++ compiler (g++) v4.6.3 on Linux.

Comment: There are "move semantics" in the upcoming (current?) C++ standard. And yes, STL vectors do a deep copy, and that's what you're getting with your code

Comment: [Rvalue references and move constructors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors)

Comment: In case you're trying to get rid of the temporary copies, maybe you could have each nested function take a reference parameter to your vector, which you modify...

Comment: We'd need to see the definition of your `my::Vector` class to know the answers of your questions for sure.  And are you sure you need a wrapper class to add the extra functionality?  Can it not be handled by free functions?

Comment: @MihaiTodor Thanks But I want to have exact same interface for all functions as part of library design.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks. Yes I think I need a wrapper class as I am offering std::vector interface to the user but internally doing memory management on CUDA and OpenCL devices of vector data.

Comment: I have tried printing "std::cerr" in copy constructor to see how many times it is called but it seems it is not called at all (not even once)? What is happening as I am sure it should be called.

Comment: [Copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In copy constructor, is it invoking copy constructor of std::vector? or assignment operator

In your case, it's creating an empty `std::vector`, then copy-assigning it. Using an initialiser list would copy-construct it directly, which is neater and possibly more efficient:

```
Vector<int>::Vector(const Vector& c) : m_vec(c.m_vec) {
    ....
}
```

> Just to confirm, std::vector creates deep copy

Yes, copying a `std::vector` will allocate a new block of memory and copy all the elements into that.

> With nesting of calcOnCPU() in calc() each returning Vector of int: 2 or 1 copies of Vector will be created?

That's up to the compiler. It *should* apply the "return value optimisation" (a special case of *copy elision*), in which case it won't create a local object and return a copy, but will create it directly in the space allocated for the returned object. There are some cases where this can't be done - if you have multiple return statements that might return one of several local objects, for example.

Also, a modern compiler will also support *move semantics* where, even if the copy can't be elided, the vector's contents will be moved to the returned object rather than copied; that is, they will be transferred quickly by setting the vector's internal pointers, with no memory allocation or copying of elements. However, since you're wrapping the vector in your own class, and you've declared a copy constructor, you'll have to give that class a move constructor in order for that to work - which you can only do if you're using C++11.

> How could I avoid multiple copies in case of such simple method nesting? Inline functions or there exist another way?

Make sure the structure of your function is simple enough for copy elision to work. If you can, give your class a move constructor that moves the vector (or remove the copy constructor, and the assignment operator if there is one, to allow one to be implicitly generated). Inlining is unlikely to make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One clarification about "or remove the copy constructor to allow one to be implicitly generated" What would happen if I remove my copy constructor? What implicitly generated copy constructor can do differently?

Comment: @user600029: It is not what the implicitly defined copy constructor can do, but what you inhibit the compiler from doing if you declare your own. In particular, the compiler (C++11) will provide a move constructor if possible, but it will not do so if you provide a copy constructor (or assignment operator...). That is, by not providing one of the operations that inhibit the generation of a move constructor you can get a boost in performance for free (or when you update the compiler if you are still using C++03)

Comment: @user600029: If you remove your copy constructor, then the implicit one will copy each object member - in many cases, this is exactly what you want. And if you do remove it (and the assignment operator, and don't declare your own move constructor or move assignment operator), then the compiler will give you a move constructor as well.